# Delete onmousout when onmouseclick

Tags: html

I have an mouseover event to change my rowcolors, I want it to the highlighted color when clicking on the row. How do I do this?

```
<tr onmouseover="this.className=\'highlight\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'normal\'" onclick="showDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="normal">
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Do you want to keep the highlight color when you have clicked the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple example, there are a number of different ways to do this.

**NOTE**

I edited the example following the original poster adding the row markup. It now matches more closely what that demonstrates.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addHighlight(el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf('Selected') == -1) {
        el.className += ' Selected';
    }
}

function removeHighlight(el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf('hold') == -1) {
        el.className = el.className.replace('Selected','');
    }
}

function setHighlighted(el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf('hold') == -1) {
        el.className += ' hold';
    } else {
        el.className = el.className.replace(' hold','');
    }
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">

tr.Selected td {
  background-color: #f00;
}

</style>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr onClick="setHighlighted(this);" onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="setHighlighted(this);" onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="setHighlighted(this);" onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="setHighlighted(this);" onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
 <td>ipsum timor alle re</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfect, one more question what about clicking the row again, can I remove the highlight again?

Comment: It should. That's why the setHighlighted checks for hold and adds or removes it.

Comment: Works fantastic.
One last question about this topic. I have tried to replace the highlight class with Selected when event is mouseclicked. But it won't work.

Comment: I did a search and replace in Notepad, changing all references to Selected, and it worked. When you say "won't work", what do you mean? It won't highlight?

Comment: I don't want to replace all of them. What I'm trying to do is that when clicked on an row the class becomes Selected, when mouseover and mouseout the classes switches the way I want.
clicked: Selected
mouseover: Highlight
mouseot: Normal

Comment: I'm not sure how you've integrate it in with any other code, so it's difficult to say why it isn't working. My hunch is the .Selected class is not setup correctly in your CSS, but I would have to see the underlying html, js and css to tell.

Comment: Ok, hold on a second. So you want to actually only hold the highlight for one mouseover, then discard? So mouseover (highlight), click (highlight), then mouseover (still highlighted), then mouseout (not highlighted)?

Comment: @Jared Farrish:
no mouse-> class 'normal'
mouseover -> class 'highlight'
mouseout -> class 'normal'
mouseclick -> class 'selected'

Comment: Ok, then all you should have to do is replace the term 'highlight' with 'Selected' in the JS (addHighlight/removeHighlight) and then have a css class for .Selected, and it should work. My guess is the css is not selecting correctly Use Firebug's Inspect Element to see if the Selected class is being added/removed, and to check if the class is seeing the css rule.

Comment: This is all that is happening: mouseover -> ensure highlight is added to tr; mouseout, if hold class is not set, remove highlight; click adds/removes hold class, which tells the mouseout handler whether the highlight class should be removed. So all you need it to do is add/remove a Selected class instead of a highlight class.

Comment: @Jared Farrish
`code` function setHighlighted(el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf('highlighted') == -1) {
        el.className += ' highlighted';
    }
} `code`
It alsmost works, but when I mouseover the highlighted that class is removed.

Comment: I edited the code I posted to show the use of Selected. I only changed highlight in four places - three in the JS and once in the CSS. Note I added tr. to the Selected class to make it clear how that selector is working (on the TR row element) to make the highlight occur.

Comment: Good job @Jared Farrish, at mouseover the wrong class is selected, that should be highlight. Can you explain the code, what is with 'hold' and '-1'?

Comment: Hold is a flag - "this row is currently holding it's highlight". -1 is what indexOf returns when there was no match (0 being the very beginning of the string's position). So I look for hold and either add/remove on click, or detect whether it's there or not before removing Selected.

Comment: For instance, if var str = 'I am a string';, I is in the 1st position (0), n is in the 7th position (6), and f is in the 13th position (12).

Comment: If you are having problems still, can you post a link to the page with code in use?

Answer (score 0):

This could all be done with CSS, for instance

```
tr { background:white; }
tr:hover { background:blue; }
tr:active { background:red; }
```

For example

Comment: This won't take into account multiple rows which may be selected, or browsers (IE) that don't fully support css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="mytr_'.$row['id'].'" onmouseover="this.className=\'highlight\'" onmouseout="if(!this.isselected || this.isselected==0){this.className=\'normal\';}" onclick="showDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="normal">
```

and in your function showDetails use foreach or while to reset all selected rows and after you all reset then put clickedID.isselected=1;

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the `onmouseout`-event with `this.onmouseout=null` in your `onclick`:

```
<tr ... onclick="this.onmouseout=null; showDetails('.$row['id'].');" ...>
```